# Android - узнать о начале ввода с клавиатуры

Tags: android, edittext, android-softkeyboard

Есть EditText. Как можно узнать, что была нажата какая-либо клавиша программной клавиатуры при вводе, сразу после ее нажатия? Именно клавиша, отвечающая за вывод символа, то есть другими словами, нужно получить уведомление о начале ввода в EditText.

Есть такая запись:

```
 editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int id, KeyEvent event){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some key pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
 });
```

Но здесь Toast появляется только при нажатии клавиши Enter и только в однострочном `EditText`

Answer (score 2):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some key pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```